# Team Foundation Server: HTTP code 400 - Bad Request

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, bad-request

we have a problem with Team Foundation Server. "**HTTP code 400: Bad Request**" error message shows up at various places (see attachment with screenshots) in Visual Studio (e.g. after click to Pending Changes, Source Control Explorer, Get latest version etc...).

There are 3 developers in our company. Error message is quite random, sometime it works and then error message show up... Or the error message shows up only on computer 1 and computer 2. Third computer is OK. Next day, the developer 1 is all right and the other two have error message...

**Our enviroment:**

*Client:*
3x PC, Visual Studio Professional 2015, Windows 10

*TFS server:* 
Win2012 R2, TFS 2015 Update 3

*SQL Server:* 
SQL 2012 std

**Attachments:**

[Screenshots with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HFDR.png)

[Another screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxTSl.png)

**Log from wireshark:**

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): POST /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [POST /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: POST
        Request URI: /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 14.102.25619.0, Pro, SKU:31)\r\n
    X-TFS-Version: 1.0.0.0\r\n
    Accept-Language: cs-CZ\r\n
    X-TFS-Session: eb5ed6e7-04ea-4ae5-8444-211cd145a568, Connect\r\n
    X-VSS-Agent: TFS: af687f1c-d07d-42ca-b185-15a5a10d20ca\r\n
    Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8\r\n
    SOAPAction: "http://microsoft.com/webservices/Connect"\r\n
    Host: tfssrv:8080\r\n
    Content-Length: 244\r\n
        [Content length: 244]
    Expect: 100-continue\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n
    Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://tfssrv:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx]
    [HTTP request 1/3]
    [Response in frame: 1933]
    [Next request in frame: 1935]
    File Data: 244 bytes

eXtensible Markup Language
    <s:Envelope
        xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <s:Body>
            <Connect
                xmlns="http://microsoft.com/webservices/">
                <connectOptions>
                    1
                    </connectOptions>
                <lastChangeId>
                    331005
                    </lastChangeId>
                <features>
                    1
                    </features>
                </Connect>
            </s:Body>
        </s:Envelope>



Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    POST /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): POST /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [POST /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: POST
        Request URI: /tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 14.102.25619.0, Pro, SKU:31)\r\n
    X-TFS-Version: 1.0.0.0\r\n
    Accept-Language: cs-CZ\r\n
    X-TFS-Session: a5d31d36-1b78-4602-b765-e2a7082abef9, Connect\r\n
    X-VSS-Agent: TFS: af687f1c-d07d-42ca-b185-15a5a10d20ca\r\n
    Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8\r\n
    SOAPAction: "http://microsoft.com/webservices/Connect"\r\n
    Host: tfssrv:8080\r\n
    Content-Length: 244\r\n
        [Content length: 244]
    Expect: 100-continue\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip\r\n
    Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://tfssrv:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx]
    [HTTP request 2/2]
    [Response in frame: 695]
    File Data: 244 bytes


Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n]
            [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
        Status Code: 400
        Response Phrase: Bad Request
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\r\n
    Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\n
    Date: Mon, 31 Oct 2016 13:23:34 GMT\r\n
    Connection: close\r\n
    Content-Length: 326\r\n
        [Content length: 326]
    \r\n
    [HTTP response 2/2]
    [Time since request: 0.000720000 seconds]
    [Prev response in frame: 692]
    [Request in frame: 694]
    File Data: 326 bytes


Line-based text data: text/html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\r\n
    <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>\r\n
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>\r\n
    <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>\r\n
    <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>\r\n
    </BODY></HTML>\r\n
```

Comment: Are you using any proxy in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down the issue, you could try to reset IIS server. And if you are using any proxy, try to remove the proxy and try again. Also check the **event view** on the TFS server to see if there are any related info for trouble shooting.

According to your error screenshot and error ID *TF400813*. Next time when you can't connect to TFS through VS, you can try this:

1. In the top right corner of Visual Studio, you will find a colored
   box with your name or your initials inside. click the down arrow and
   then Account Settings. In the opening window, please click "Sign
   out" in the upper left part of the window.
2. After a restart of Visual Studio and signing back in, the error
   should be gone.

Comment: Hi Patrick, there is nothing in event log. We've already check this... We tried restart IIS server, re-login in VS, restart VS, we're not using any proxy server... Nothing helps, the problem is still there...

Comment: Restarting IIS actually worked for me. Straight after TFS installed successfully, I had the problem. Then restarted IIS and was able to link Visual Studio with TFS fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and found the Application Tier had somehow got corrupted.

1. Open TFS Administration Console, click on the Application Tier and look at the Application Tier Summary. I had lots of errors on this, so I clicked 'Remove Features (click on the server name at the top of the tree) and then reinstalled the Application Tier using the Upgrade option.
2. Click on 'Change URL's'. Test the Notification URL and Server URL. In my case, the Notification URL was not working.
3. Open IIS Manager, Click on Sites->Team Foundation Server and click Bindings on the right side bar.
4. Add binding using the host name, IP Address as 'All Unassigned', and port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem. We accessed the server by its name (tfs.domain.com) and some members of the team had many errors with check-in mainly. We changed the name of the server by its **ip address** and it worked.

It sounds strange because we were able to access http://tfs.domain.com from browers, but Visual Studio TFS had problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Client-Side Solution**

If the solution still persists even after repair the TFS server, then try the below steps.

> 1. Open Visual Studio as Administrator.
> 2. Open Source Control Explorer from Team Menu.
> 3. Select dropdown against the Workspace and edit or create a new workspace.
> 4. Create a new folder in drive and attach to a new workspace(created in step 3)
> 5. Now your TFS server folder shows all the projects.
> 6. Start to get latest from source.

Hope your error will be gone.

Note:- Restart the Visual Studio before step 1.